# Set default values for headers in Restangular globally

Tags: angularjs, restangular

How can I set content-type globally in Restangular ?

I can set it for each request using custom method, like this

```
Restangular.oneUrl("auth").customPOST(), undefined, undefined, {
  'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
}).then(function(resp) {
  // do something with resp;
});
```

and it works, but I want to set it globally so I don't have to write content type for each request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature has been added with issue https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/105 .
You can set default values for headers like this:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'});
```